# Heroku - Express and React app showing blank screen when deployed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I am having a difficult time trying to figure out what is going on here. When I deploy my React/Express app to Heroku, everything builds and deploys with no errors, but my React frontend is completely blank.

I am getting this errors in the browser console:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < 1.b1e0c624.chunk.js:1
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < main.48d62be5.chunk.js:1 
 manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.
```

Here is how my `server.js` file is setup to send the root `index.html` file:

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

app.get('*', function(_, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join('/app/client/build/index.html'), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send(err);
    }
  });
});
```

And this is what the top portion (code redacted for brevity) of my React apps `package.json` looks like:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://radiant-tor-66940.herokuapp.com/",
  "private": true,
}
```

I figured setting the homepage in the client's `package.json` would do it but nothing. I am really unsure what to do here. I am thinking that something might be off with a path or something like that.

***Update***

This is still an issue for me. Below I have shared more code in hopes that this is can aid in my case. I am getting a new error this time when the page loads:

```
{"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"stat","path":"/app/server/client/build/index.html","expose":false,"statusCode":404,"status":404}
```

This error above is being sent from the error block in this code:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('/client/build/index.html', { root: __dirname }, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    }
  });
});
```

I have changed my `server.js` file to serve the `index.js` file like this versus using a template literal (trying anything at this point):

```
    //Express
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
    //Core Node Modules
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');

    //Middleware
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(express.json());

        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build')));

        app.get('*', function(req, res) {
          res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname }, function(err) {
            if (err) {
              res.status(500).send(err);
            }
          });
        });

    app.listen(port, err => {
      if (err) console.info(`Error: The server failed to start on ${port}`);
      else console.info(`****** Node server is running on ${port} ******`);
    });
```

This is the root level `package.json` for my server. I have added the `heroku-postbuild` script to build the React app located in `client`:

```
      "scripts": {
        "test": "jest",
        "start": "node server/server.js",
        "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build"
      },
  "engines": {
    "node": "~9.10.1",
    "npm": "~5.6.0"
  }
```

Here is the `package.json` for the React app located in `/client`:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000/"
}
```

Here is what the files looks like on the Heroku server:

1st image: Root Directory
 2nd image: /client directory
 3rd image: /client/build directory
 4th image: /client/build/static directoy

[image: Root Directory]

[image: /client Directory]

[image: /client/build directory]

[image: /client/build/static directory]

Comment: Does `heroku logs --tail` add any insight?

Comment: Can you insert your build script - a `webpack.config.js` or something? It's hard to tell why the files are not loaded without knowing if they are generated at all.

Comment: @stever I wish, I am getting `GET / 500` at `path:"/"` errors and I can see it log out when the request for the `index.html` file 500's. It's telling me there is a 500, but it's not giving any suggestions as to why.

Comment: @felix I have updated the original post to show the Heroku directory via `heroku bash` post build and deployment. I also included the build script for `heroku-postbuild`.

Comment: The ~ on the directory indicates that you are on the home directory of the user. Can you output what you send to sendFile function?

Comment: I feel for ya @maison.m . Do you have build packs installed? https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app-buildpack

Answer (score 3):

The issue was in my `server.js` file.

Originally it was `express.static(path_join(__dirname, '/client/build'))`

it needed to be: `express.static(path_join(__dirname, '../client/build'))`

This is the case because my `server.js` file is located in `/server` and it was trying to find `/client/build` inside of `/server` instead of the root app directory on Heroku.

Comment: This helped me as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/65488031/10431732

Answer (score 1):

As we don't have access to your server, it's hard to tell the reason behind your problem. I would guess you misconfigured your express server as those three error messages indicate, that the server only returns the `index.html` file.

And as HTML is not valid Javascript, you get unexpected token errors.

I would also guess, that the following line has no effect at all, which means there are no files in this folder (or not those you want to access).

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
```

Comment: Using `heroku run bash` I can `cd client/build` on the Heroku server and can see that when I deploy from local, the react app does build and has files in `client/build`, one of which is `index.html`. I am under the impression that the React app is `served up` through the `index.html` file as that is the root for the application to begin with.

Comment: Well off course your app is served by your `index.html` as React needs a host document and a root element to begin with. But your problem lies in the wrong responses of your server. The server responds with `index.html` despite the request of `/static/main.48d62be5.chunk.js`. Does this file exist in your folder?

Comment: I do not have that file in my folder. Would it be created and put there when the build process is ran?

Comment: I don't know. That depends on your build process. As it is requested from your (generated?) `index.html` i guess it should be there. Note that the hash in the filename might change each time you run your build process.

Comment: the `index.html` is definitely in there and when I `console.log` out `${__dirname}/client/build/index.html` from my server, I can see it spitting out the correct path to the `index.html` file in the bash terminal on the Heroku server.

Comment: Yes, you said that already. And without, you wouldn't even see a white page. But what you need are those JavaScript files. This is the code, which renders your whole page.

Comment: I have an entirely different React app up and running on Heroku. When I use `heroku run bash` and `cd client/build` on this particular application, the build folder looks identical to the build folder on the application I am having an issue with. Both followed the same process. I am unsure of where these `.chunk.js` files come into play, but it is not anywhere in the directory of the application I have up and running on Heroku successfully.

Comment: well, which files do you have? Can you update your question with more information about your build processes and which files exist in which folder?

Comment: thanks for sticking around to help. I have updated the original question with a lot more information.